Old movie about a musician and insects in his garden
I am looking for a movie that my father has watched over 40 years ago. He doesnt remember too many details but the story goes something like this:
A pianist lives in a house with a beautiful garden, which is inhabited by bugs. There's some sort of war going on between the two. One day the pianist composes a masterful piece of music, which he sends in to a contest. Winning this would mean a lot of money. However one of the bugs manages to alter the letter somehow (possibly a change of address) and the pianist ends up running out of money and having to sell the house. The garden is destroyed and a high-rise is being build. Reising that they have nowhere to go the bugs ensure that the composed piece wins after all. This allows the pianist to buy the top floor of the high-rise and build a beautiful gardens, so he and the bugs end up coexisting.
He doesn't remember whether it was an animated movie or even a short movie. It is also possible that it wasnt a pianist but another musician. It might be a german movie.

Could it possibly be: Mr. Bug Goes to Town (1941) ?

Hoppity discovers that the Songwriter and his wife are waiting for a
  "check thing" from the Famous Music publishing company for the
  songwriter's composition, "We're the Couple in the Castle." But C.
  Bagley Beetle and his henchmen "steal" the check. Hoppity threatens to
  expose C. Bagley Beetle's nefarious scheme, but Beetle and his
  henchmen seal Hoppity inside the envelope and hide it in a crack in a
  wall.
As the wedding is going on Smack and Swat discover that a construction
  company is going to be erecting a skyscraper on the property of the
  former home of the Songwriter (now foreclosed by the property owners
  because of the "lost" check), and therefore also on C. Bagley Beetle's
  property where the Lowlanders moved in thanks to Beetle's
  "generosity."
/////
Hoppity tells the citizens all about C. Bagley Beetle's finding the
  check and hiding it, but Hoppity's story doesn't actually change
  anything; they are still in danger and are angry at Hoppity. He
  leaves, dejectedly, but then overhears the Songwriter and his wife
  (watching the demolition of their old property wistfully) talking
  about wishing that the publishers had bought his song and reflecting
  on their now-dashed dreams and how they would have built a penthouse
  on top of the new skyscraper.
/////
While the building is being built, the check finally arrives in the
  hands of the Songwriter and "We're the Couple in the Castle" becomes a
  massive hit. Meanwhile, Hoppity leads an exodus from the Lowlands to
  the top of the skyscraper, where he is sure the Songwriter has built a
  home and invited the bugs to live there. They get to the top, which at
  first appears to be barren. The bugs are angry, and Hoppity is mocked
  by Mr Creeper until Buzz, Ambrose, and little Murgatroyd look a little
  farther over a wall and call the others over to see the new penthouse
  and its "Garden of Paradise" that Hoppity had been describing. Honey
  and the rest of the Lowlanders live there happily ever after in their
  new home. And as Ambrose looks over the edge, he remarks, "Look at all
  the human ones down there. They look just like a lot of little bugs!"

More on the plot can be found here.
